# Basic Discrete Math?

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics

Can anyone help with a basic Discrete Math Question?
I need to know if the following statement is true or false.

For n to be prime, it is necessary for 2^n - 1 to be prime.

I have tried plugging in nonprime numbers to see if I can get another prime number, with no success. I know I have to be doing something wrong, and there has to be an easier way.

Comment: "I have tried plugging in nonprime numbers to see if I can get another prime number" - what? As in, you've been trying composite values of n and seeing if you get a prime 2^n-1? That wouldn't tell you anything. You need to try prime n and look for a composite 2^n-1.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. I have been trying to do that.

Comment: Also, this is a pure math question, not a programming question. It belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Keep plugging. You give up too easily.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 2):

From the wiki page [Mersenne Prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime) : The first four Mersenne primes (sequence A000668 in OEIS) are 3, 7, 31, and 127.

Since 11 is a prime number - 2^11-1 = 2047 = 23 * 89 :)

Answer (score 0):

If n is composite, i.e., n=a·b with non-trivial factors a, b, then obvious factorizations exist via geometric sums

```
2^(a*b)-1=(2^a)^b-1^b=(2^a-1)*((2^a)^(b-1)+(2^a)^(b-2)+…+2^a+1)
```

Thus if 2^n-1 is a prime, then also n must be a prime, which in general is not very helpful.